# Looking for a good Mootools Javascript tutorials

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

I have been very impressed by the Mootools AJAX sites and demos and I want to learn it so that I can use it on my sites.

But I havent been able to get any good tutorials which teach it from the very basics. Can someone give me some pointer/links to some sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

www.clientcide.com is your friend :)

Answer (score 3):

[Up the moo herd](http://keetology.com/blog/2009/07/00-up-the-moo-herd-mootools-tips-and-tricks) is a worth to read tutorial series.

Comment: totally agree + 1 - keeto and aaron newton are by far the best tech writers in the mootools community and core-teams.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mootorial.com/

http://www.consideropen.com/blog/2008/08/30-days-of-mootools-12-tutorials-day-1-intro-to-the-library/

http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/mootools_tutorials_and_example/

these are a good start.

Comment: keep in mind that these are old and the api has changed significantly since they were first written - as well as what is being deemed best practices. mootorial is the classic in the genre and the thing that started a lot of us back in the day...